# Is this publish/subscribe implementation safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-ptr

I am working on a custom publish/subscribe system for intra-process communication. Assume that publishers want to send a piece of data (a message) to all registered subscribers, and all these entities possibly execute inside a different thread. Every connection between a publisher and a subscriber is implemented as a **lockfree queue of `shared_ptr<const Message>`**.

Because I need to avoid dynamic allocation, each publisher pre-allocates a pool of shared pointers to message. When the user calls `Publisher::publish(msg)`, I fetch a message from the pool (if available), copy the user-provided one as `*msgptr_from_pool = msg`, and push such shared pointer to all queues connecting to all registered subscribers. In order to fetch the message shared pointer from the pool, I check its `use_count`. If it is one, it means that no subscriber is still using (reading) the message, and I can safely recycle it. Notice that I don't remove messages from the pool. Simply, once that they have been pushed to the queues, their use count will be > 1.

On the subscriber side, the user consumes messages shared pointers from the queue, but never stores the consumed shared pointer anywhere. The user provides a callback of the kind `void(const Message& msg)` and never actually sees the underlying shared pointer. Therefore, once all subscribers have done with a message, its use count will be one.

My question is: considering the guarantees that the standard C++ mandates regarding shared pointers in a multithreaded context, is this pattern safe? More particularly, I need to have the guarantee that **when I see that a shared pointer has use count = 1, I can safely modify the pointed-to message because no other thread can read it anymore**

**EDIT: as requested, I am adding a simplified code which can be compiled 
and run**

Full compilable simplified example (requires a recent version of Boost.Lockfree, C++11 support and must be linked against pthread)

```
#include <boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <thread>


template <typename Msg>
class Publisher
{

public:

    typedef std::shared_ptr<Msg> MsgPtr;
    typedef boost::lockfree::spsc_queue<MsgPtr> Queue;
    typedef std::shared_ptr<Queue> QueuePtr;

    Publisher(QueuePtr q):
        _q(q)
    {
        // some pool size
        const int pool_size = 10;

        // preallocate msg pool
        for(int i = 0; i < pool_size; i++)
        {
            _pool.push_back(std::make_shared<Msg>());
        }
    }

    bool publish(const Msg& m)
    {
        // find a msg ptr with use_count = 1
        auto it = std::find_if(_pool.begin(), _pool.end(),
                               [](const MsgPtr& mptr)
                               {
                                   return mptr.unique();
                               });

        // it does not exist..
        if(it == _pool.end())
        {
            return false;
        }

        // it exists, fill it with the provided message
        **it = m;

        // try to push to the queue
        return _q->push(*it);
    }

private:

    QueuePtr _q;

    std::vector<MsgPtr> _pool;

};


template <typename Msg>
class Subscriber
{

public:

    typedef std::shared_ptr<Msg> MsgPtr;
    typedef boost::lockfree::spsc_queue<MsgPtr> Queue;
    typedef std::shared_ptr<Queue> QueuePtr;
    typedef std::function<void(const Msg& m)> Callback;

    Subscriber(QueuePtr q, Callback cb):
        _q(q), _cb(cb)
    {

    }

    void consume()
    {
        _q->consume_all([this](const MsgPtr& mptr)
                        {
                            _cb(*mptr);
                        });
    }

private:

    QueuePtr _q;
    Callback _cb;

};


// test util to generate random strings
std::string random_string(std::string::size_type length);

/**
 * @brief The MsgType struct is the message type
 * to be exchanged between threads. Contains a random 
 * string and its hash, to kind of check for data corruption
 * due to wrong synchronization
 */
struct MsgType
{
    std::string message;
    size_t hash;

    MsgType()
    {
        message = random_string(256);
        hash = std::hash<std::string>()(message);
    }

    bool check() const
    {
        return std::hash<std::string>()(message) == hash;
    }

};

std::atomic_int cb_called(0);

// test callback
void on_msg_recv(const MsgType& msg)
{

    if(!msg.check()) // we received garbage, abort
    {
        abort();
    }

    cb_called++; // increment global counter
}

// test main
int main()
{
    using Queue = boost::lockfree::spsc_queue<std::shared_ptr<MsgType>>;
    const int queue_size = 10;


    auto queue = std::make_shared<Queue>(queue_size);

    std::atomic_bool run(1);
    std::atomic_int pub_msgs(0);

    auto producer = [&]()
    {
        Publisher<MsgType> p(queue);

        while(run)
        {
            MsgType m;
            pub_msgs += p.publish(m);
        }
    };

    auto consumer = [&]()
    {
        Subscriber<MsgType> s(queue, on_msg_recv);

        while(run)
        {
            s.consume();
        }
    };

    std::thread tp(producer);
    std::thread tc(consumer);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));

    run = 0;

    tp.join();
    tc.join();

    printf("Message published: %d \n", pub_msgs.load());
    printf("Callback called    %d times \n", cb_called.load());

}

std::string random_string(std::string::size_type length)
{
    static auto& chrs = "0123456789"
                        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    thread_local static std::mt19937 rg{std::random_device{}()};
    thread_local static std::uniform_int_distribution<std::string::size_type> pick(0, sizeof(chrs) - 2);

    std::string s;

    s.reserve(length);

    while(length--)
        s += chrs[pick(rg)];

    return s;
}
```

On my system the output is

```
Message published: 967752 
Callback called    967751 times
```

Comment: As apple apple mentioned, please include code that is a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I have edited my question and added an example that can be compiled and run with minimal dependencies.

Comment: Two more comments on your question: Firstly, don't piece it together from different edit sections. It should be one complete piece. Same goes for additional info in comments. Secondly, can you rephrase this without using templates? If the code being a template is relevant, what are your requirements on its type?

Comment: For this simplified example, the message is required to be default-constructible and copy-assignable.